# app engine dispatch static files to a CDN url

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

We want all our static requests to an CDN, and the CDN is a Google Storage Object.

```
  expamle.come/static/file.js => cdnurl.com/example-bucket/file.js
```

And since we're using Storage Objects from the same platform ( Google obviously), we thought this should be a piece of cake, but I couldn't find any doc in Google.

here's our current `dispatch.yaml`.

```
dispatch:
  # Default service serves simple hostname request.
  - url: "*/example.com"
    service: default

  # Send all api traffic to the api backend.
  - url: "*/api/*"
    service: backend
```

We want this :

```
  # Send all api traffic to the static CDN.
  - url: "*/static/*"
    ourbound: https://cdn/our-bucket/static/*
```

On a side note, is it a good idea to have another service that uses an NGINX in front of our app that does this?

Comment: I don't know if what you specifically want is possible (it does not seems logical to me to do that, GAE should not dispatch to a CDN). I think you should rather create a subdomain cdn.example.com and loadbalance it to your bucket. And if possible, do not use a bucket but the Cloud CDN service.

Comment: @ThisIsMyName thanks for your answer, but how does load balancing is related to redirecting ? To me, the term "load balancing" just means balancing load of the requests. And Google buckets are faster than most CDNs

Comment: Maybe something like that? https://medium.com/@marco_37432/create-a-custom-domain-cdn-with-google-beta-7ad9531dfbae

Comment: Why not use GAE's static file serving infrastructure? - it is just like a CDN...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=228&v=HkJxy22P5gk&feature=emb_logo

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/dispatch-yaml) file is to route requests to different services rather than to define url to serve the static files. You can nonetheless define which service will take care of serving the static files. The, to define where and how the static files are retrieved you should modify the app.yaml of the service that will handle the requests, in this case the app.yaml for the default service.

One option would be to serve the static files directly from the application. For this you just need to put the files in the `./public` folder and set your handlers as explained in the following part of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/serving-static-files#configuring_your_static_file_handlers).

Second option would be to let Google Cloud Storage serve the static files. This would require creating a bucket, putting the assets therein and allowing public access to the files. This might be done through the urls provided by Cloud Storage as could be seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/serving-static-files#example_of_serving_from_a_bucket).

Regarding your question of load balancing, I don't think it makes sense to put another service for GAE service for load balancing as it is not the intended use for such product.

Comment: Monad, thank you. However, I don't want to create another service to serve my static files, that would defeat the purpose of having a CDN in the first place, because I then have to manage my service's load etc.

Comment: @Milad If I'm not mistaken you already have the service default serving the web requests so with the first option it wouldn't be necessary to create another one. Let me know if I misunderstood something.